# installing openbabel3 with pip

Tags: python-3.x, pip, openbabel

I tried `pip install openbabel --log log_file` and I got the following error:

```
Collecting openbabel
  Using cached openbabel-2.4.1.tar.gz (74 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: openbabel
  Building wheel for openbabel (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for openbabel
  Running setup.py clean for openbabel
Failed to build openbabel
Installing collected packages: openbabel
    Running setup.py install for openbabel ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/59/zn1rl7b13tqc7t2njskzp6th0000gn/T/pip-install-d2aqd_xf/openbabel/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/59/zn1rl7b13tqc7t2njskzp6th0000gn/T/pip-install-d2aqd_xf/openbabel/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/59/zn1rl7b13tqc7t2njskzp6th0000gn/T/pip-record-i_0qytcj/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.7m/openbabel Check the logs for full command output.
```

Here pip is an alias for pip3.

The log file is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cwq3chlj9qu60b7/log_file.txt?dl=0) (I am not sure if you can read it, this is my first time sharing a file)

note: A few days ago I opened a second user on my computer, I don't know how it affects things but maybe that's the reason.

I am using Mac OS Catalina.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a much simpler way than building openbabel manually. `brew install openbabel` works for `openbabel3`

Check the link: http://openbabel.org/wiki/Category:Installation

Answer (score 1):

From a quick look at the log file it looks like it wont install as it cant find a version for Mac OS, only for Windows, however the following may be useful as a workaround to that: [How to Install openbabel for Python 3.6 on macOS Sierra 10.12.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42195236/how-to-install-openbabel-for-python-3-6-on-macos-sierra-10-12-3)